# How to create Dir with unique name inside Directory

Tags: php, linux, file, directory

I've created a file via

```
$my_dir = '/var/example'

$file_path = tempnam( $my_dir, '' );
```

Then I tried to convert temp file (`$file_path`) to dir.

There is no function `tempdir`.

How can I create dir with unique file name inside `$my_dir`?
Even, if `$my_dir` contains a lot of sub dirs.

Dir name needs to be unique and not necessarily to be random.

Suggested question and answer - is not an answer for my question.

Suggested answer possible could conflict if there is subdir with generated name by `uniqid` function.
I need to guarantee - there are no conflicts with existing subdir inside `$mydir`.

I need to solve the problem similarly how `tempname` works. Analogically, but for directories.

Acording to @RiggsFolly
I've found this solution

```
$file_path = tempnam( $books_dir, '' );
unlink($file_path);
mkdir($file_path);
```

But theoretically there could be conflict and mkdir then could return `false`,
If I start this script multiple times in parallel mode.

Good solution, but not ideal.

Comment: Do you want to create a Temporary Directory, or a permanent one

Comment: Permanent with a random unique name

Comment: @RiggsFolly, its not the answer for my question.

Comment: But it gives you all the pieces you need to write code to do what you want

Comment: It gives me nothing with my problem

Comment: `unlink($file_path); mkdir($file_path);` However this will create a directory like `abcd.tmp` so you may want to remove the `.tmp` extension